# Java CompletableFuture get its request

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I am creating list of `CompletableFuture` for  creating some async request. However, when I get the response of it, I do not know which response that I get. Is there a way to know request body that is send via `CompletableFuture`?

Here is the code for the list of `CompletableFuture` which result want to be mapped with its request.

```
List<CompletableFuture<UserResponse>> userResponse = new ArrayList<>();

for (User user: users) {
    UserRequest userRequest = UserRequest.builder()
        .id(id)
        .build();
    CompletableFuture<UserResponse> userCompletableFuture = this.userClient
        .checkUserRequest(
            userRequest
        );
    userResponse.add(userCompletableFuture);
}

CompletableFuture.allOf(userCompletableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
    .exceptionally(ex -> null)
    .join();

IntStream.range(0, userCompletableFutures.size())
    .forEach(index -> {
        try {
            UserResponse userResponse = userCompletableFutures.get(index).get();

            // Do something with the response and map it with the request.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

And here is the `UserClient`

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<UserResponse> checkUserRequest(UserRequest request) {
    CheckUserUrl url = new CheckUserUrl(apiUrl);

    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
        this.sendHttpRequest(
            HttpRequestDTO.builder()
                .url(url)
                .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                .request(new HttpEntity<>(request))
                .build(),
            UserResponse.class
        )
    );
}
```